# Webpack - No Output File, No Errors Reported

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, webpack, babeljs

I am learning Webpack and going through it again and again. In the latest build, there is something very strange going on. CLI reports everything is well & the output file `dress_aphrodite.js` is `emitted`, yet its nowhere to be found in the folder.

Here are the logs:
From CLI:

```
http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/
webpack result is served from /app/
content is served from ./app
Hash: 5334867c12acfa65ba90
Version: webpack 1.12.9
Time: 1966ms
                    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    dress_aphrodite.js  390 kB       0  [emitted]  main
dress_aphrodite.js.map  479 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} dress_aphrodite.js, dress_aphrodite.js.map (main) 354 kB [rendered]
    [0] multi main 52 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./~/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js 209 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/core-js/shim.js 4.31 kB {0} [built]
    [3] ./~/core-js/modules/es5.js 10.2 kB {0} [built]
    ...
  [263] ./~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

So everything looks good above. Yet, there is no `dress_aphrodite.js` file in the main folder or `./app` folder.

Here is the webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require ('path');
var webpack = require ('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry : [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './app/da',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080'
    ],
    resolve : {
        extension : ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    },
    output : {
        publicPath : '/app/',
        filename : 'dress_aphrodite.js'
    },
    debug : true,
    devtool : 'source-map',
    devServer : {
        contentBase : './app'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test : /\.js$/,
                include : path.join (__dirname, 'app'),
                loader : 'babel-loader',
                query : {
                    presets : ["es2015"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And finally, incase, anyone needs the package.json file, here it is:

```
{
  "name": "dress_aphrodite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dress_aphrodite.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Any help as to why the output file is not being emitted / rendered?

Thanks

**Edit**: Tried without the `Output.publicPath` (as suggested by YuWu), still no change. Changed it to `path` property & still no change as well.

**Edit 2**: As a test, I added the `html-webpack-plugin` into the `webpack.config.js` file to see if it would be emitted by webpack and yes, apparently that too has been emitted and yet I cannot see.

**Edit 3**: (Post generous conversation with YuWu) : The `webpack-dev-server` is running fine and displaying the window.alert in the js file along with the dynamic html file created via `html-webpack-plugin`. I recall installing the `webpack-dev-server` globally. Could that be where the html & the js emitted files are being stored? Where can i locate the global directory in Ubuntu 15.1?
(It shouldn't be the case as package.json is pointing towards the local directory path in reference to the 'start' property...)

**Edit 4**: Here is the question I posted on webpack github issues section. My further investigation findings are also noted there in the comments.
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1736

Comment: what if you get rid of 'publicPath' in the 'output' field?

Comment: @YuWu just tried that, no change. Still no errors & no output file.

Comment: what about output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, ''),
    filename: 'dress_aphrodite.js'
  },

Comment: @YuWu , this is insane. After rebooting the system and this change 
output: {path: __dirname, filename: 'dress_aphrodite.js'}, the webkit-dev-server is working. The 'sources' tab in Chrome Dev Tools shows the html & js files. HOWEVER, they are nowhere to be found in the folder?!

Comment: @ YuWu , yes, your recommendation also works, however, the both files (HTML produced by the html-plugin & the webpack output js file are still not in the main directory or the 'app' directory)...

Comment: That's weird. Would you mind share your repository so that I can take a look?

Comment: @YuWu , apologies, I was away. Here is the Github link: https://github.com/Kay2dan/webpack_test.git

Comment: After I 'npm install' the packages you listed in the readme, and run 'webpack', I have dress.js.map, dress.js, and index.html generated in the main directory. My webpack version is 1.12.9.

Comment: @YuWu this is so strange. Im on Ubuntu, and I have reviewed the read/ write permission and all seems fine, even changed the owner from root to my user group. https://drive.google.com/a/coutallure.com/file/d/0B75s3IUopYNVOGRleGtnb25ac0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @YuWu I wonder what you think about the `edit 3` posted above in the question? Could the global directory of `webpack-dev-server` be where the html & js files are being stored?

Comment: I doubt that. I installed webpack globally, and run 'webpack' would generate all those files. Do you wanna try webpack@1.12.9 alone without webpack-dev-server?

Comment: @YuWu I just ran the `webpack da.js dress_aphrodite.js` and it emitted the file correctly in the app folder. i.e. I can see the file in the app folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's expected that you won't see anything output to disk with this configuration.

You've defined `webpack-dev-server` as one of your entry points, and have started to set up the dev server via the `devServer` property in the project

[`webpack-dev-server`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) works by running webpack, and storing the contents of the compilation in memory. This way, when you make a change to one of your files and `webpack-dev-server` recompiles the changes, it can do so quickly.

By storing these files in memory, we remove I/O latency allowing webpack to complete recompilations quickly and serve files to your browser quickly.

If you want files to be output onto disk, you should run `webpack` instead of `webpack-dev-server` and remove `webpack-dev-server/...` from the entry point in your config.